# CRUD Generator Utiltiy for AngularJS

Tags: .net, angularjs

Is there a CRUD generator utility , that can generate controllers + views in MVC with must have AngularJS in .Net?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own fairly easily using a code generator like CodeSmith or MyGeneration

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/

Comment: One for WebAPI + Angular14: https://github.com/capesean/codegenerator3